# Binary search to Find K Closest Elements of an array

Tags: java

I am learning binary search in  leetcode from problem [Find K Closest Elements - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-k-closest-elements/)

> Given a sorted array, two integers `k` and `x`, find the `k` closest elements to `x` in the array. The result should also be sorted in ascending order. If there is a tie, the smaller elements are always preferred.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [1,2,3,4,5], k=4, x=3
> Output: [1,2,3,4]
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: [1,2,3,4,5], k=4, x=-1
> Output: [1,2,3,4]
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. The value k is positive and will always be smaller than the length of the sorted array.
> 2. Length of the given array is positive and will not exceed 104
> 3. Absolute value of elements in the array and x will not exceed 104

It's official solution:

> Approach 2: Binary Search and Two Pointers
>
> **Algorithm**
>
> The original array has been sorted so we can take this advantage by the following steps.
>
> 1. If the target `x` is less or equal than the first element in the sorted array, the first `k` elements are the result.
> 2. Similarly, if the target `x` is more or equal than the last element in the sorted array, the last `k` elements are the result.
> 3. Otherwise, we can use binary search to find the `index` of the element, which is equal (when this list has `x`) or a little bit larger than `x` (when this list does not have it). Then set `low` to its left `k-1` position, and `high` to the right `k-1` position of this `index` as a start. The desired k numbers must in this rang [index-k-1, index+k-1]. So we can shrink this range to get the result using the following rules.
>
>    - If `low` reaches the lowest index `0` or the `low` element is closer to `x` than the `high` element, decrease the `high`index.
>    - If `high` reaches to the highest index `arr.size()-1` or it is nearer to `x` than the `low` element, increase the `low`index.
>    - The looping ends when there are exactly k elements in [low, high], the subList of which is the result.

The implementation

```java
public class Solution {
    public List<Integer> findClosestElements(List<Integer> arr, int k, int x) {
        int n = arr.size();
        if (x <= arr.get(0)) {
            return arr.subList(0, k);
        } else if (arr.get(n - 1) <= x) {
            return arr.subList(n - k, n);
        } else {
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(arr, x);
            if (index < 0)
                index = -index - 1;
            int low = Math.max(0, index - k - 1), high = Math.min(arr.size() - 1, index + k - 1); #1????

            while (high - low > k - 1) {
                if (low < 0 || (x - arr.get(low)) <= (arr.get(high) - x)) #2????
                    high--;
                else if (high > arr.size() - 1 || (x - arr.get(low)) > (arr.get(high) - x)) #????
                    low++;
                else
                    System.out.println("unhandled case: " + low + " " + high);
            }
            return arr.subList(low, high + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 questions about the implementation

1. `low = Math.max(0, index - k - 1)`, I assumed it as `low = Math.max(0, index - k - 1)`, since low's left position is `[index -k +1]`not `[index-k-1]`.
2. `if (low < 0 || (x - arr.get(low)) <= (arr.get(high) - x)) #2????`, since low was set as `low = Math.max(0, index - k - 1),` and it will increase forwards, is it necessary to check `low < 0`, the same as `else if (high > arr.size() - 1 || (x - arr.get(low)) > (arr.get(high) - x)) #????`
3. `while (high - low > k - 1)`, what's the benefit of it over `high - low >=k`?

Comment: Numbers 1 and 2 are missing the question part.

Comment: "while (high - low > k - 1), what's the benefit of it over high - low >=k?" Both of these comparisons are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to say, it is the lowest quality official solution I read in Leetcode, as you said, it indeed has many defect in this solution. I will explain it one by one.

**For Question1:**
you are kind of correct here, we should change `Math.max(0, index - k - 1)` to `Math.max(0, index - k)` but not `Math.max(0, index - k + 1)`. because when the target number `x` is not in array and left `k` is the result we want, we should start from `index - k`.
for example:
`Input: [1,2,3,10,11], k=4, x=2`
index is `3`, and we should start from `index-k=2`

**For Question2:**
you are correct, `low < 0` and `high > arr.size() - 1` are unnecessary check here. you can just remove it.

**For Question3:**
`high - low > k - 1` is equals to `high - low >= k` in integer comparison.
These are just two different programming habits, choose the one you like.

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Question 3:  a reasonable explanation might be: `>=` is two operations of `>` and `==`.

Comment: I think in instruction level, they cost silmiliar, I always choose the one which type code less. : )

Comment: Thank you.I am now assured to chose `>=` or ｀<=`, cos they are straightforwards and cost zero mental efforts.

Comment: In my opinion, sometimes correctness is more important than performance, choose the one you familiar which make less mistake.